# OpenWrt GUI installation failure

Tags: openwrt, luci

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocwbh.png)

I have installed Openwrt on my router and now want to install the web GUI, which is Luci. Accessed the router and logged in but it gives me the problems:

- Signature check failed
- Remove wrong signature file

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit this file and then try **opkg update**.
just do the following:-

```
vi /etc/opkg/distfeeds.conf
src/gz chaos_calmer_luci http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ar71xx/generic/packages/luci
```

Firstly remove link from above file which contain luci's link and then add this above link in the file, and then try

```
opkg update
opkg install luci
```